# C# WebAPI Deserializing a List returns null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble in converting some string to JSON.

I use C# WebAPI to Deserialize string

1. First： `List<GetBookInfoModel> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetBookInfoModel>>(strOutput01);`
2. Second：`List <GetBookDetInfoModel> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetBookDetInfoModel>>(strOutput01);`

And my Json String is like：

1. First： `[{"allbook ":{ " count01 "  :3}, " late ":{ " count02 ":0}}]`
2. Second： `[{"num ":1, " bookname ":"AAAAA","FinTime ":"2017"},{"num ":2, " bookname ":"iOS","FinTime ":"2017"},{"num ":3, " bookname ":"Visual","FinTime ":"2017"}]`

And my Model class is like..

```
public class GetBookInfoModel
{
    List<GetBookSecondInfoModel> allbook { get; set; }
    List<GetBookSecondInfoModel> late { get; set; }
}
public class GetBookSecondInfoModel
{
    public string count01 { get; set; }

    public string count02 { get; set; }
}


public class GetBookDetInfoModel
{
    public string num { get; set; }

    public string bookname { get; set; }

    public string FinTime { get; set; }
}
```

But now it  returns null.

How can I resolve this problem?Thanks.

Comment: In the JSON strings, there are a lot of spaces in your property names. Try to fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there are 3 issues for the former.

1) The properties of `GetBookInfoModel` should be `public`.

```
public class GetBookInfoModel
{
    public List<GetBookSecondInfoModel> allbook { get; set; }
    public List<GetBookSecondInfoModel> late { get; set; }
}
```

2) The unnecessary spaces between paired quotes in JSON should be removed.

3) Both `allbook` and `late` in JSON should be followed by `[]`.

```
[{"allbook":[{ "count01"  :3}], "late":[{ "count02":0}]}]
```

Similar for the latter.